# how to provide an alert when there is no record in the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When i click on submit button, Based on hidden field ID we are getting the value from database and loaded in the table. if value is present the table should be loaded otherwise i need to display alert as 'there is no record'.Currently the value is loaded in the table but it is does not show an alert when there is no record.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="InteractGeneric"><b>Interact Generic List</b></a>

<div class="table-responsive" id="findValue" style="display:none;height:500px;">
                        <table id="example" class="display table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>S#</th>
                                    <th>Generic Name</th>
                                    <th>Interact Generic</th>
                                    <th>Interact Description</th>

                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#InteractGeneric').click(function () {
                var GenericID = $("#hdnGenericID").val();
                $("#example tbody tr").remove();

                $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',

                    url: '@Url.Action("GenericInteractionNewDetails")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { GenericID: GenericID },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var items = '';
                        $.each(data.GenList, function (i, item) {
                            if (data.GenList == undefined)
                            {
                                alert("Nothing Found");
                            }

                            $("#findValue").show();

                            var rows = "<tr>"
                            + "<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.GenericName + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.GenSuperClass + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.GenClass + "</td>"
                            + "</tr>";
                            $('#example tbody').append(rows);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                        alert("Message: " + r.Message); d
                        alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                        alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GenericInteractionNewDetails(int GenericID)
        {
            List<GenericMaster> GenList = dGMSP.GenericInteractionDetails(GenericID);
            var data = new { GenList = GenList };
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Alert does not work:

```
if (data.GenList == undefined)
    {
      alert("Nothing Found");
    }
```

Comment: Because it will never be `undefined` - your passing back a collection (although it might be empty) - use `if (data.GenList.Length == 0) { alert(..) }` before the `$.each(...`

Comment: Output:  [Image1](https://ibb.co/b1Ajd7)   [Image2](https://ibb.co/bOXKBS)  [image 3](https://ibb.co/dD6Pd7) alert does not work @StephenMuecke

Comment: Sorry (typo), its `length` (lower case)

Comment: you can use `length` property of the list to get to know whether the list is empty or not

Comment: thank you sir @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

```
if (!data.GenList.length)
{
  alert("Nothing Found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the response data is an array,

```
    if (data.GenList.length === 0) {
       alert("No items found")
    }
```

If the response is an object,

```
   if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(YOUR_OBJECT)) {
       alert("No item found")
   }
```

Comment: I can able to do only up vote  to you ..because already  @Nitesh answered my question ..Thanks

Comment: @IvinRaj Thanks for up voting. When I was typing he submitted the answer. So no worries. He should have the credit. Thanks.